# how to find and add drivers to 13.10?

Tags: drivers, 13.10

Just bought a new computer with splendid features inside...

(Hp envy dv7-7300/ct  i-7 core. n-vidia 2GB video... a "beats by dre" speaker with built in bass...)

since I cleared the windows off from the laptop and installed

Ubuntu 13.10, the performance sensible slowed down, so as video process got weaker,
speakers sounds painfully weak standard factory sound, and there is no options or equalizer.

to make them better.

I am assuming

- I might have to wait for the latest updates to get these features supported

Or which is more likely

- I did not install the additional software I should have...

Question is:

- how can I make them coop?

Much appreciated for the guidance and help.

Answer (score 0):

For Display

If you go to

System Settings >Software and Updates > Additional Drivers you can see which all drivers are available for Nvidia.

Or you can go to Nvidia website and search for driver corresponding to your graphics card/

http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx